# in-Message copied in out-Message

Tags: apache-camel

I have this simple route in my RouteBuilder.

```
from("amq:MyQueue").routeId(routeId).log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Log: ${in.headers} - ${in.body}")
```

As stated in the doc for HTTP-component:

```
Camel will store the HTTP response from the external server on the OUT body. All headers from the IN message will be copied to the OUT message, ...
```

I would like to know if this concept also applies to amq-component, routeId, and log?  Is it the default behaviour, that IN always gets copied to OUT?

Thank you,
Hadi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: The **concept of IN and OUT messages is deprecated** in Camel 3.x.

This is mentioned in the [Camel 3 migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_getout_on_exchange) and also annotated on the [getOut method of the Camel Exchange](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#getOut--).

However, it is not (yet) removed, but what you can take from it: **don't care about the OUT message**. Use the `getMessage` method and don't use `getIn` and `getOut` anymore.

To answer your question:

Yes, most components behave like this

- Every step in the route takes the (IN) message and processes it
- The body is typically overwritten with the new processing result
- The headers typically stay, new headers can be added

So while the Camel Exchange traverses the route, typically **the body is continuously updated and the header list grows**.

However, some components like [aggregator](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/aggregate-eip.html) create new messages based on an **AggregationStrategy**. In such cases nothing is copied automatically and you have to implement the strategy to your needs.